# Heat Map- how to add colour division and legend

Tags: heat-map

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to colour the certain counties of England + legend about the colour's meaning. Here is my code which will give me the chosen counties of England on a map. But I would like to add numbers from my excel file about how many repairs on which properties are on each county similar to the link below.

```
GB0 <-readRDS("gadm36_GBR_0_sp.rds")
GB1 <-readRDS("gadm36_GBR_1_sp.rds") # England, Ireland, Scotland, Wales
GB2 <-readRDS("gadm36_GBR_2_sp (1).rds")
GB3 <-readRDS("gadm36_GBR_3_sp.rds") # Cities

x<-(GB3$NAME_2=="Wirral" | GB3$NAME_2=="Sefton"|GB3$NAME_2=="Lancashire"|GB3$NAME_2=="Cheshire East"|
      GB3$NAME_2=="Blackpool"|GB3$NAME_2=="Blackburn with Darwen"|GB3$NAME_2=="Rochdale"|GB3$NAME_2=="Bolton"|
      GB3$NAME_2=="Oldham"|GB3$NAME_2=="Wigan"|GB3$NAME_2=="Salford"|GB3$NAME_2=="Knowsley"|GB3$NAME_2=="Warrington"|
      GB3$NAME_2=="Liverpool"|GB3$NAME_2=="Manchester"|GB3$NAME_2=="Stockport"|GB3$NAME_2=="Trafford"|
      GB3$NAME_2=="Halton"|GB3$NAME_2=="Tameside"|GB3$NAME_2=="Cheshire West and Chester"|GB3$NAME_2=="Bury"|
      GB3$NAME_2=="Saint Helens")


County<-GB3[x,] 
plot(County)
plot(County[x,],border="blue",add=TRUE) #Notice add=T; this draws on top of current plo
text(coordinates(County),
     labels=County$NAME_3,col="red",cex=0.7)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You had a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but do not seem to be using that so I removed it.  You also had a very long string that was not rendering so I removed that too.

Comment: this isn't a heat map - what software are you using?